# Deleting row with cursor in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to delete field names where the field "FULL_NAME" = 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am not getting an error message, but nothing is being deleted from my file.  I am not sure why the delete field isn't working.

```
import arcpy
roads = "C:/hwy"
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(roads, ["FULL_NAME"]) 
for row in cursor:
    row[0] == "1":  
        cursor.deleteRow()
del row
del cursor
```

Comment: Try using a with block for your cursor. Is your feature class participating in a topology or geometric network? Is your FULL_NAME a text field or numeric? if it's numeric you will need to specify if row[0] == 1: (no quotes) C:/hwy doesn't look like a feature class name, should it be c:/hwy.shp?

Comment: Wouldn't creating a feature layer and feeding that into a `DeleteFeatures` be more efficient?

Comment: Is the field containing `1` a string or integer field?

Comment: 1 is a string the hwy is actually in a geodatabase I just simplified the naming for the demo

Comment: @Dan is correct, arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(roads, 'kill_these',"FULL_NAME = \"1\"") then arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management('kill_these') is far more efficient, but that doesn't solve *this* problem precisely. How does your code look now? Can you confirm that roads doesn't participate in a topology or network?

Comment: Roads does not participate in typology or network -- I get that delete feature is more efficient, but I should be able to do it this way and am trying to figure out what is wrong

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a benchmark on the DeleteFeatures method vs the UpdateCursor approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    row[0] == "1":  
        cursor.deleteRow()
```

try this:

```
    if row[0] == "1":  
        cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: This did not change anything

Comment: @user10720 Try refreshing your table to see if the changes took effect.

Comment: Great, two things: 1) consider wrapping your `cursor` in a `with` statement as you see in the documentation (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) and 2) please consider accepting @PolyGeo's answer so we can consider this question resolved.